# Permission to get user email with Facebook PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have a working integration with facebok api via PHP SDK and working login. Now I tried to add the permission for email as well with the following code, but when trying to connect/login to the app the email is not requested.

```
// login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($me) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'req_perms' => 'email',
  ));
}
```

The error must be in this code since everything else works fine. Thanks!

Comment: Does anybody have any experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the comma you have after 'email' and redirect the browser to $loginUrl, like this:

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
  array(
    'req_perms' => 'email'
  )
);

echo '<script>top.location="'.$loginUrl.'";</script>';
die();
```

## EDIT

This was how it was done back in the day, now facebook have changed their API:s. For a more current solution, look at the other answers on this question.

Comment: it worked with `req_perms`?? or we need to use `scope`

Answer (score 7):

To request the "email" permission, you need to use the correct parameter and update your login URL creation. Here's how you can modify the code:

```
 // login or logout URL will be needed depending on the current user state.
if ($me) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'scope' => 'email', // Use 'scope' to request permissions
  ));
}
```

Make sure to include the correct "scope" parameter in the getLoginUrl function call. Additionally, if you want to request additional permissions, you can include them in the "scope" parameter separated by commas. For example:

```php
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
            'scope' => 'email,user_activities,user_friends', // Include 
                additional permissions
      ));
```

also additional permission must be passed to scope variable

```
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
   'scope' => 'email, user_activities '
 ));
```

For a complete list of available permissions, please refer to the Facebook Authentication Permissions [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/#user_friends_perms).

With these changes, the login process should request the "email" permission as well as any additional permissions you include in the "scope" parameter.
updated answer is ;

```php
// Redirect the user to the Facebook login page with the 'email' permission
header('Location: ' . $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'scope' => 'email'
)));

exit;
```

It uses the header function to redirect the user to the Facebook login page with the 'email' permission requested. The 'scope' => 'email' parameter is used to specify the requested permission. The exit statement ensures that the script execution stops after the redirection.

This approach is more direct and follows best practices for handling redirects in PHP. It simplifies the code and focuses on achieving the specific goal of requesting the 'email' permission during the Facebook login process.

Answer (score 3):

This should work with the PHP SDK:

```
header('Location:'.$facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'scope' => 'email'
)));
exit;
```